# This keyword in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hey I am new in C# and ASP.NET.

I tried to learn ASP.NET in this [Site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_managing_state.htm). In section of Session State, there is an example code (shown below). But I still don't get it, what function of "this" keyword on that code. 
Can someone explain to me, what "this" keyword function in that code?, because I already tried to remove the "this" keyword, but the result still same.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
   String mystr;

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      this.lblshstr.Text = this.mystr;
      this.lblsession.Text = (String)this.Session["str"];
   }

   protected void btnstr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      this.mystr = this.txtstr.Text;
      this.Session["str"] = this.txtstr.Text;
      this.lblshstr.Text = this.mystr;
      this.lblsession.Text = (String)this.Session["str"];
   }
}
```

Comment: first search this simple keyword and ask again

Comment: Yes, I already search that keyword.
This keyword means refer to this class/object. In javascript I get the function of this keyword, but I still dont get it what function of "this" keyword in that example code.

Comment: It's redundant in that particular code but some people prefer to use that style.

Comment: People sometimes type `this` to trigger IntelliSense in the code editor, and leave it there afterwards although it is not needed.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks for the answer Connor. Btw I want to ask you something. Better if I learn c# first or asp.net first if I want to make web apps using asp.net web forms?

Comment: You will need to have a basic knowledge of the language to understand the code examples when reading about ASP.NET. Here is a post on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179433/awesome-asp-net-and-c-sharp-tutorials-for-beginners

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks Connor for the answer. In that post contain many links to learn ASP.NET. I will try to uncover each site and decide which is best suite for me.

Answer (score 0):

'this' always refers to the object that has called the member function. We can access instance variables of the current object by using this. It increases readability of the code plus if we have instance variable and the local variable with the same name then it is used to refer instance variable instead of the local variables of the function.